# Android camera preview stay white, but no crash

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm trying to create an application with the camera on Android. I used code I was able to found in the android doc, on internet etc. just as test.
The camera preview is still white, nothing crashes tho but no preview at all is showing up. Can't find if it comes from my emulator or my code ... I use integrated Webcam as camera in the emulator.

Any help please ?

here is my camera preview class:

```
package com.guillaimej.testapplication.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraInputView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraInputView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.guillaimej.testapplication.app.CameraInputActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/camera_layout"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">


</FrameLayout>


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/domygif"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/flask"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="snapIt"
    android:layout_weight="0.0"/>


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/returnButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/return_button"
    android:layout_weight="0.0"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.guillaimej.testapplication.app" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListOfFileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_of_file" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraInputActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_camera_input" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***EDIT:***

Here is the activity where I use the camera preview:

```
package com.guillaimej.testapplication.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import  android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.Toast;
import  android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;


public class CameraInputActivity extends Activity{

    private ImageButton returnButton = null;
    private ImageButton domygifButton = null;
    //private Camera camera = null;
    private CameraInputView cameraView;
    private SurfaceHolder previewHolder;

    private FrameLayout cameraLayout = null;

    // Check if the camera is free and return it
    private static Camera isCameraAvailable() {
        Camera cam = null;
        try {
            cam = Camera.open(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return cam;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_input);

        returnButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);
        returnButton.setOnTouchListener(new ReturnButtonListener());

        domygifButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.domygif);

        cameraLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_layout);

        Camera camera = isCameraAvailable();
        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        cameraView = new CameraInputView(this, camera);
        cameraLayout.addView(cameraView);
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you have the rest of the code from the tutorial. Do you have a `getCameraInstance(...)`; how about your `onCreate(...)`, what's that look like?

Comment: Is mCamera.open() happening somewhere?

Comment: Yes it happens in my mainActivity, I'll post the code asap, thanks !

Comment: Ok, I've udpated my post with the code of the activity where I use the camera,
Thanks !